# Extending ExternalLink in Tapestry 4

Tags: tapestry

Is it possible to extend `ExternalLink` in Tapestry 4? When I try, it seems as though none of my parameters are getting populated. I've tried explicitly re-annotating the abstracts in my subclass, but that doesn't take care of things like `getExternalService()`. Any insight into how this thing's actually initialized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `ExternalLink.jwc` from Tapestry's source to see how the component is configured. As for `getExternalService()`, the .jwc says:

```
<inject property="externalService" object="engine-service:external"/>
```

So you could do the same thing with an annotation like so:

```
@InjectObject("engine-service:external")
public abstract IEngineService getExternalService();
```

---

It looks like you should be able to extend `ExternalLink`, but in my experience T4 components are not always easy to subclass and the framework tends to encourage composition over inheritance. If you run into more problems, perhaps it would be easier to wrap an `ExternalLink` with your custom component instead? I.e. create a new component that only contains a single link component?